# How can i group millions documnets based on interval using mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I have **Millions** of documents in the mongodb collection.

I want to group the documents based on minute and hour interval.
I created the index for timestamp.
I tried below mentioned query, but it's took too much time or timeout.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: 1696405061,
        $lte: 1697009861,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        interval: {
          $minute: {
            $toDate: {
              $multiply: ["$timestamp", 1000],
            },
          },
        },
      },
      timestamp: { $last: "$timestamp" },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
]
```

How can i resolve the issue.

I tried with **skip **and **limit **also still i'm facing same issue.

Comment: I don't see any grouping attempts in your code. What do you like to achieve?

Comment: How many documents do you expect as result? 24/60 or more? First, you should store timestamp values as `Date` objects rather than a number.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, may it will helpful.

```
{
  _id: {
    interval: {
      $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", date: { $toDate: "$timestamp" } 
}
    }
  },
  timestamp: { $first: "$timestamp" },
  count: { $sum: 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should convert the numeric data into proper `Date` objects. Then you can derive the minute (or hour) and create an index on it.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { timestamp: { $type: "number" } },
   [{
      $set: {
         minute: {
            $dateTrunc: {
               date: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$timestamp", 1000] } },
               unit: "minute"
            }
         }
      }
   }]
)
db.collection.createIndex({ minute: 1 })
```

Then you can group it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$minute",
         timestamp: { $min: "$minute" },
         count: { $count: {} }
      }
   }
])
```

You may also try this version, it could be faster:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: {minute: 1} },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$minute",
         timestamp: { $min: "$minute" },
         count: { $count: {} }
      }
   }
])
```